# Does a new version of an Android application still have the old version permissions even if they are no longer declared in the new manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Suppose a user has installed version v0.1 of an application that has 3 permissions (perm1, perm2, perm3) declared in its manifest file. And he update this application by installing new version: v0.2, but in the manifest file of this version, we find only 2 permissions (perm1 and perm2).

My question is: is the 0.2 version of this application still able to use permission perm3 since the user has accepted it previously? Or the fact that perm3 no longer appears in the manifest file means that perm3 permission is no longer assigned to it.

Comment: It shouldn't exist. Why do you ask?

Comment: I thought that maybe the permssions are user-related (user created especially for each installed application), once these permissions are assigned, they always follow the user even after an update -_-, but after checking , My reasoning is false so every version of an application will just have the permissions that are declared in its propore manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Every app will only have the permissions declared in it's own manifest and is not affected by the permissions contained in a manifest in some previous version of it.